# Questions regarding DotNetNuke 6.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

I needed help on some issues regarding DotNetNuke 6.2 ....

1) If a layman such as marketing executive logs into the site, then he should be able to change the layout of the page by moving the content blocks around as per his design requirements.

for eg Left content block needs to be moved to right side. Left bottom content block needs to be moved to the bottom.

This tasks will not be done by the developer. Is there a example which does not require change/modification in skin files... Kindly provide a code example...

2) Is it possible to host a DotNetNuke site under a custom MVC 4 application and is communication possible between them ?

for eg... exchanging token, logged in user information etc

Kindly provide a code example....

Comment: The first one should be possible already and if its not you can add support yourself.  The second one should be possible.  Since you have provided no code, I won't provide any code, I will show the exact same effort as you.

Comment: Hi regarding the first question, the answer is yes.  The best way to find out though is to set up a site and play around with.  As there is work involved to set it up.  As to an example setting up a site will go a long way to answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is all about the skin that you use.  If you have a LeftPane and a ContentPane for example.  Any user with edit permissions to the page can move a module from the LeftPane to the ContentPane, or move a module up/down with respect to other modules in the pane.
2. Yes, you can, but you have to be a bit careful when nesting both inside the same application structure.